# Logstash Java OutOfMemory only when use_prepared_statements=>true in jdbc when synchronizing initial huge dataset

Tags: java, jdbc, logstash, ojdbc

We are getting `Java OutOfMemory` during initial loading a huge dataset of ~70 Mio records with Logstash and jdbc into Elastic.
Java Heapsize is 4GB, but even with 8 or 16GB the situation is the same.

The very same dataset can be loaded successfully without `use_prepared_statements` (using literals).

We have successfully loaded the whole view once with `use_prepared_statements=>false`, but to have it more efficient even for delta loads, we would like to use prepared statements.
Our idea is to use `jdbc_fetch_size=>1000` to limit the amount of data within one fetch.
According documentation, using `jdbc_page_size` or `jdbc_paging_enabled` is not in effect when using prepared_statements. It would even not be efficient because of the complex view behind the scene, which would not be efficient when multiple queries using offsets each time for the initial load.

Using prepared statements work within Oracle well and we see fetches were around 1 mio records out of ~70 mio done when Logstash failed with OutOfMemory failure.

Our current logstash config:

```
input {
    jdbc {
        type => "sim_list"
        jdbc_validate_connection => true
        jdbc_driver_library => "/pkg/moip/otc/apps/ls-otc-tmsp_tua2/conf/ojdbc6.jar"
        jdbc_driver_class => "Java::oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:oracle:thin:@db-server:1521:TA2A"
        jdbc_user => "test"
        jdbc_password => "testpwd"
        tracking_column => "last_import"
        use_column_value => true
        tracking_column_type => "timestamp"
        prepared_statement_bind_values => [":sql_last_value"]
        prepared_statement_name => "get_sim_list_tua2_v5"
        use_prepared_statements => true
        last_run_metadata_path => "/pkg/moip/otc/data/ls-otc-tmsp_tua2/jdbc/sql_last_run_sim_list_tua2_v5"
        statement => "SELECT simlist.*, simlist.LAST_UPDATE as last_import
FROM (SELECT *
      FROM V_SIM_LIST_VIEW
        WHERE last_update between (?) - 1/86400 and sysdate
          ORDER BY last_update ASC) simlist"
        # run every 5 seconds
        schedule => "*/5 * * * * *"
        connection_retry_attempts => "3"
        jdbc_fetch_size => 1000
    }
}

filter {
    mutate {
        copy => {
            "%{di_id}" => "[@metadata][_id]"
        }
        split => { "user_ids" => "," }
        split => { "option_ids" => "|" }
        split => {"apn_ids" => "|"}
        split => { "ip_address" => "|" }
    }
}

output {
    if [type] == "sim_list" {
        elasticsearch {
            hosts => ["https://ece.mydomain.com:443"]
            index => "sim_list_tua2_v5"
            document_id => "%{di_id}"
            #doc_as_upsert => true
            manage_template => false
            cacert => "/pkg/moip/otc/apps/ls-otc-tmsp_tua2/conf/certs/ca.crt"
            ssl => true
            ssl_certificate_verification => true
            user => "logstash_write"
            password => "${LSWRITEPWD}"
        }
    }
}
```

Idea is, to use one big query for initial load, which should be split by `jdbc_fetch_size`.
Next schedules shall use `:sql_last_value` to get incremential changes.
However, it breaks soon after first round about 1000 fetches.

Currently, it seems, the `jdbc_fetch_size` doesn't work as expected. So we have no clue, why it fails all the time.

We tested with ojdbc6.jar and odbc10.jar against Oracle 19c, but no difference.
Logstash is running with Java 11.0.10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found following nice working workaround:

Using logstash with two different configs (anyway required):

1. for Initial-Sync: Using literals `use_prepared_statements=>false`
2. for Delta-Sync: Using `use_prepared_statements=>true`

In addition, since we have to use two different logstash configs anyway, we used optimizer hints for the SQL of Initial-Sync and without those hints for the SQL of the Delta-Sync. So, we have optimal config for both scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using [fetch,limit and offset](https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-basics/oracle-fetch/) in the query used by prepared statement. Like, we do the batching at the SQL level, rather than JDBC level. Send in the offset with each batch that you want to load. I'm not an expert on Logstash, but this should be configurable.

Comment: Thanks, but it would require paging enabled, which starts the very same query multiple times with different offset and limits. As mentioned in question, the sync query is complex and would cause a very high redundant load on DB.
We've optimized the query, so that we can do a delta-load for small number of changes within acceptable time.

Comment: Maybe write a REST API proxy in Spring Boot, which will get the data in the way that you want and have elastic just query this. It should be easy, since you only need one endpoint and some standard library to query the DB. Or you need to find someone who's very good at Elastic. No